# How to use a query as a source for a report in MS Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, report

I did the following in MS Access: I made a form which had a combo box and a button. You select an option from there and click on the button and it is supposed to open a report. Now, I wrote a query selecting a few fields from a table and in the where clause, gave the condition as `where name=str(combo1.value)` and the report source was specified as this query. Now, when I select the value and click on the button, it opens a blank report. How can I make it load only those particular values?

I am not saving the combo box value anywhere. It said that it would remember the value for later use. Am I doing the right thing by not saving it? What should I do to make this work? Please help me!

**Edit:** The combo box is using values from a column 1 in a table X. I've not bound the value to any field and am using the "Remember the value for later use" option provided. The combo box is essentially a list of hotels and the report is a list of people staying at the selected hotel. When I put the ID of the field (as defined in the X), it works. But the thing is, it should refer to the names of the hotels and not the ID, which I am supposed to enter in a popup that asks for it. What do I do?

**Edit 2:** The query is as follows:
`SELECT Table_1.Hotel_Name, Table_2.Name_of_Delegate, Table_2.Address, Table_2.City, Table_2.Center, Table_2.Spouse_Present, Table_2.No_of_Children, Table_2.No_of_Guests, Table_2.No_of_Rooms
FROM Table_1 INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID=Table_2.Hotel_of_Residence
WHERE Table_1.Hotel_Name=FormName.Combo7.Text;`

When I click on the button (which opens the report), it asks for the name of the hotel in a popup box. How can I avoid this? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Open your form in design mode.  Click the combo box to select it.  Then right-click to open a popup menu and select Properties.  On the property sheet, select the Data tab.  Then tell us what is in the boxes next to these properties: Row Source Type; Row Source; Bound Column.  If the Row Source is a query, copy that query SQL and paste it into your question.

Comment: @HansUp: There is no control source. Row Source is `SELECT [Table_Name].[ID], [Table_Name].[Name] FROM [Table_Name];`. Row Source Type is Table/Query. Bound Column is 1 (which I assume shows the names I wish to be displayed in the combobox.) When I select a name and click on the **Display Report** button, it invokes an embedded macro to open the report. In the where condition in the macro designer, I have provided the clause to populate it(the report) based on the value selected, but it doesn't seem to be working. Please help.

Comment: @HansUp: Also, I'd be grateful if you could help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492391/how-to-populate-a-text-box-based-on-the-value-in-a-combo-box-in-ms-access-2007)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *WhereCondition* with the [DoCmd.OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032%28office.12%29.aspx) as a "dynamic WHERE clause" for your report's record source.  Use something like this in the click event of the command button which opens your report.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReport", , , "[name]=" & Me.combo1
```

Remove the WHERE clause you added, `where name=str(combo1.value)`, from the report's query.

I surrounded *name* with square brackets because *name* is a reserved word.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)

**Edit**: In a comment, you said this about the combo box:

"Row Source is SELECT [Table_Name].[ID], [Table_Name].[Name] FROM [Table_Name];. Bound Column is 1 (which I assume shows the names I wish to be displayed in the combobox.)"

When you refer to the value of a combo box, that value is the value of the "Bound Column".  So in your case, the bound column is 1, which means the combo value will be [Table_Name].[ID].  However, you want to open your report based on the [Name] column of the combo.  So change the bound column of the combo from 1 to 2.

Comment: @HansUp: Can you please give me a step by step guide to doing this? I'm getting it wrong somewhere and I don't know what's wrong. I tried doing it your way and @bluefeet's way and even tried a mix of the two. The closest I got to was when I had to put the ID of the field that needed to be selected, rather than the string stored in the field, ie, put 6 instead of Hotel XYZ, and it works. But put Hotel XYZ and it throws an error. Next, the place to input this, which really shouldn't come, is a popup box. I am very confused about the procedure. Please help me!

Comment: @HansUp, @bluefeet: I think the problem is that I'm providing the names in the combo box, but it expects the ID to complete the query and prepare the report. How do I rectify this?

Comment: @HansUp: I was looking up [DoCmd.OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032%28office.12%29.aspx) and I noticed that `FilterName` is one of the parameters to be passed. Should I write a simple `Select` query and then save that and use it here and pass the parameter as you have suggested? Would that work better?

Comment: Edit your question to show us the row source for the combo box.  If the row source is a query, show us the query SQL.  If the row source is a value list, show us that.  And tell us what you have as the combo's Bound Column property.

Comment: @HansUp: Hello? Can you please help me out? This is the only thing that is holding up the completion of my project :(

Comment: Help you out with what?  I thought this had been resolved.  You had included a link to another question, but following that link leads to a message that the question has been removed by its author.  In any case, I have not committed nor will I ever commit to serving as your unpaid personal support person.

Comment: @HansUp: You're right. I'm sorry :( It's just that I've been stuck with this one problem since even before I posted it online and its getting very frustrating for me to be stuck with this. I'll try changing the bound column and see how it works out.

Comment: Two days ago I suggested you change the bound column from 1 to 2.  You accepted my answer.  To me, that indicated you had done as I suggested and it resolved your problem.  Then yesterday you were back requesting help ... for what?  I had no idea.  Unfortunately it appears you were asking for more help without even having tried changing the bound column.  This is not a good situation.  I certainly understand frustration.  But you have to find some way to keep your frustration from impairing your ability to communicate effectively.  This is not **just** a technical problem.

Answer (score 1):

To open a report using the value of your combobox, in your report query you need to do the following:

```
SELECT fields
FROM table
WHERE YourValue = [Form]![FormName]![ComboBox Value]
```

You have to specify the name of the Form, plus the value so the report query knows the value.  Hope this helps.

Comment: But that would mean the report would always require the form be opened in order to run. Using the WhereCondition argument of the DoCmd.OpenReport command allows you to filter the report at runtime in any way you need, while still being able to run the report completely unfiltered.

Comment: you are correct but in the original question it states that he would be opening a report from a form with a combo-box button trigger.

Comment: Yup, I just reread it again and I see where I missed the original request.